# Meteor Iron Router Parameter-defined Controller?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm looking for a way to specify a controller to use with a route parameter.

I've tried:

```
Router.route('/:sort', {
  name: 'feed',
  controller: function() {
    this.params.sort + 'Controller'
  }
 });
```

__

```
Router.route('/:sort', {
  name: 'feed',
  lastParam: function() {
    return lastParam = location.href.split('/').pop()
  },
  controller: this.lastParam + 'Controller'
});
```

But it doesn't seem like `this` is available in the controller key and setting it to a function gave this client error: "undefined is not a function". (controller cannot be a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you need to supply a fixed name for the controller.

Your controller, however, could be coded to delegate the functionality to other bits of code as required based on the route.